# Cosa significa "mezzano" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Artemisia*, di Anna Banti, ho letto (il corsivo è mio):

> Tuo padre che aveva scritta la denuncia nella prima collera partì per Frascati, non ti voleva vedere. Eri in mano dei vicini, dei piagnoni Stiattesi, di madonna Tuzia *mezzana*, di Cosimo furiere: chi ti suggeriva una cosa, chi un'altra, tu volesti fare a modo tuo come in confessione.

Ho cercato il significato di "mezzano" in alcuni dizionari, ma non riesco a capire qual è il suo senso in questo contesto. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Comment: Sensale, ruffiano, paraninfo...

Comment: @DaG: Qualcuno chi cerca di combinare matrimoni? O un mediatore in affari commerciali?

Comment: L'impressione, leggendo, è che sia la prima che dici, anche perché è un personaggio femminile.

Comment: @DaG:  Anche a me adesso mi sembra che sia così. Infatti, in un altro brano, questa Tuzia ([personaggio che ha esistito davvero](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processo_ad_Agostino_Tassi_per_lo_stupro_di_Artemisia_Gentileschi)) dice a Artemisia:  "Sposa Agostino, sciocca, quello ti fa andare in carrozza meglio di Cosimo".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Come indica il dizionario Treccani, "mezzano/-a" significa "intermediario/-a", e, più comunemente, chi facilita incontri d'amore, solitamente illeciti.

Comment: Benvenuta su Italian.SE, @Benedetta, e grazie della risposta!